# Syntax of the Comparative Clause Construction in English

Tags: comparative-constructions

I'm reading [Syntax of the Comparative Clause Construction in English](https://www.google.ro/search?q=Syntax+of+the+Comparative+Clause+Construction+in+English&oq=Syntax+of+the+Comparative+Clause+Construction+in+English&aqs=chrome..69i57.2583j0j8&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgdii) by Joan W. Bresnan. The author says:

> The comparative clause construction in English is almost notorious for its syntactic complexity.
>
> What accounts for the fact that in (A), (i) and (ii) can be read as (roughly) synonymous, while (iii) and (iv) cannot?
>
> A I. I've never seen a man taller than my father.
>
> II. I've never seen a taller man than my father.
>
> lll. I've never seen a man taller than my mother.
>
> IV. *I've never seen a taller man than my mother.
>
> Why does (iv) depart from grammaticality in (B)?
>
> B I. Jack eats caviar more than he eats mush.
>
> II. Jack eats more caviar than he eats mush.
>
> lll. Jack eats caviar more than he sleeps.
>
> IV. *Jack eats more caviar than he sleeps.
>
> What explains the ungrammaticality of (Civ)?
>
> C I. I am more angry today than I was yesterday.
>
> II. I am angrier today than I was yesterday.
>
> lll. I am more angry than sad.
>
> IV. *I am angrier than sad.
>
> For what reason is (iii) so much less acceptable than (iv) in (D) ?
>
> D i. Mary is more than six feet tall.
>
> ii. Mary is taller than six feet.
>
> iii. * Mary is more than five feet short.
>
> IV. Mary is shorter than five feet.

Even after I digested the author's dissertation I couldn't understand the answers to those questions except the A, where the permutation of **taller** implies the anomaly that my mother is a man. What is compared in A(IV) is  how tall a man my mother is. This is ok, I understand it.

According to the author's analyse in B the ungrammaticality is related to the transitivity of the verb **sleep**, but I don't see how this fact affects the grammar of the sentence.

I see C the most incomprehensible.

Regarding D, the author says:

> To understand the ungrammaticality of D(iii), we must note that certain adjectives, including "privative" adjectives like short, do not admit modifiers of definite measurement, but these adjectives do permit comparison: He's less short than I thought.

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparisons have to be for like grammatical structures regardless of what they are: verb, nouns, clauses. etc.

FIRST ANSWER:

lll. Jack eats caviar more than he sleeps. [the verbs are parallel;the actions of eating and sleeping are being compared;this is grammatical]

IV. *Jack **eats more caviar than he sleeps**. [comparatives have to compare like grammatical structures. (**A verb cannot be compared to a noun**)

COMPARE: Jack eats more caviar than lobster. (That is two nouns, it is grammatical.)

**Parallelism (like grammatical structure) is not present in IV**.

SECOND ANSWER:

X eats more [noun] than [noun]. Comparing like things.

COMPARE: X eat more caviar than he dreams dreams. [that is OK but silly, for sure].

That is why IV is not grammatical.

ANSWER THREE:Ill. I am more angry than sad VERSUS IV. *I am angrier than sad.

The same principle applies here:

I am more angry than (I am) sad. The comparison is for a like predicate. That's fine. AKA: I am angrier than I am sad. To be angry and to be sad are being compared.

COMPARE: I am angrier than [you, him, her, their friends etc.]. In this example a subject (noun) has to be compared to another noun. This house is whiter than that house.

**I am angrier than sad** is wrong because two parallel structures are not being compared. **That would be comparing a predicate to an adjective which is not grammatical**.

FOURTH ANSWER: Mary is more than five feet short.

In English, a person's or object's height is given by the idiom: **to be x [feet/inches or meter/millimeters] + tall**. Therefore the sentence is not idiomatic.

Unless it means: Mary is more than five feet short [of winning the race]. For a person's height though, the phrase [five feet short] is not idiomatic in English. More than x [measurement] short may only be used to express a distance from something. And then, it is not a comparative.

However, the adjectives tall and short may be used comparatively: Mary is more than five feet shorter than the wall. Mary is a foot shorter than John.

I didn't answer the first question because the OP answered it himself.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question...

> I've never seen a fatter frog than it.

Presumably, **it** is also a frog.

> I've never seen a frog fatter than it.

**It** could by anything with girth.

When one of the comparands is an entity with attributes (fat frog), the other comparand must be the same kind of entity (frog).

> I've never seen a **taller man than** my mother. <sup>fail</sup>

Mother is not a man so the comparison fails.

When one of the comparands is simply an attribute (taller), the other comparand must have that attribute in at least a minimal degree.

> I've never seen a man **taller than** my mother.

Mother does have *height* even if mother may be short. The height of the men you've seen is compared to mother's height.  If mother is short or tall, you have been living in a land where the men are no taller than she is.

When the comparands are actions rather than entities, action must be compared with action.   **he sleeps** is an action and must be compared to an action.  **eats caviar** is an action.  **caviar** is not an action.

> Jack eats caviar more than he sleeps.
>
> Jack eats more caviar than he sleeps.  <sup>fail</sup>

With respect to tall/short, long/brief.

With **more than** and comparisons of degree, what must be compared are qualities that express affirmatively extent or degree.  Adjectives like **short** and **brief** are not such, inasmuch as they do not affirmatively express extent or degree but rather the *absence* of it, negative height and negative duration.